# Decorating UserControl WPF

Tags: wpf, user-controls, contentcontrol

I want to decorate some controls in groups like:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Infrastructure.UI.ItemsGroup" ... >
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="5" Background="Red">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="25" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="0" />
            <TextBlock x:Name="ctrlGroupText" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</UserControl>
```

And use it in other XAML-files like:

```
<Grid Grid.Column="0">
    <UI:ItemsGroup GroupText="Hello World">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button>1111</Button>
            <Button>1111</Button>
        </Grid>
    </UI:ItemsGroup>
</Grid>
```

But it doesn't work. What did I wrong? :)
Thanks

Comment: It's not clear what you mean from the question.  Do you mean that you want to reuse your `UserControl` and put different content inside it?  And what doesn't work about what you have?

Comment: Yes, I want to reuse my UserControl and put different content inside it. It doesn't work means - I don't see e.g. Border and 'Hello world' text if I add some buttons (see upd2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to edit the Template for the `UserControl` instead of adding the `Border` as the Child

```
<UserControl x:Class="Infrastructure.UI.ItemsGroup" ... >
    <UserControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type UserControl}">
            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="5" Background="Red">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="25" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="0" />
                    <TextBlock x:Name="ctrlGroupText" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </UserControl.Template>
</UserControl>
```

**Update**

To set the Text for the `TextBlock` to `GroupText` you can use a Binding

```
<TextBlock x:Name="ctrlGroupText"
           Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:ItemsGroup}},
                          Path=GroupText}"
           Grid.Row="1"
           HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
```

Comment: Ok, how can I set properties to my UserControl? For example, I need to set GroupText property (x:Name="ctrlGroupText")?

Comment: @Lari13: See my updated answer for how to Bind the `TextBlock` Text to `GroupText`

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to do this in Silverlight? I tried the solution and I get an error "Setting the Template property on a UserControl is not supported.".